# "Hundir alguna cosa" vs "hundir *a* alguna cosa"

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

I know that the preposition "a" is used after Spanish transitive verbs when the direct object is a person. Example:

- El chico mató mis flores.
- El chico mató a mi hermano.

However, I have recently seen the verbs "hundir" and "sumir" used transitively with the preposition "a" when the direct object is a thing (specifically, a company and a country). Examples:

- El torpedo hundió el barco. (OK)
- El crac del mercado de valores hundió *a* la compañía.
- Las decisiones del presidente acabaron sumiendo *al* país en un caos

Why is the preposition "a" used in these sentences?

Comment: "El chico mató mis flores" sounds odd. Perhaps you meant to say: "El chico pisó/cortó/arruinó mis flores". A better sentence would be: "El frío mató mis flores" (I think "a" can also be used before "mis flores" if the owner is particularly fond of them).

Comment: There are a number of questions about "personal *a*" in this site. Also look [here](https://studyspanish.com/grammar/lessons/persa) for some more examples, and [here](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=a) (in Spanish) for an exhaustive list of cases where you must use *a* before a direct object.

Comment: @pablodf76 I'm not asking about a personal "a". However, your second link also mentions some cases when "a" is required before *things* and specifically the following rule is related to my question:  preposición a + CD - uso forzoso "ante nombres de cosa que designan colectivos formados por personas, del tipo colegio, empresa, comité, consejo, institución, comunidad, etc., cuando el verbo denota una acción que solo puede ejercerse sobre personas, y no sobre cosas: Multaron a la empresa por realizar vertidos tóxicos; Convocaron a la comunidad de vecinos para que tomara la decisión definitiva."

Comment: @Gustavson Doesn't the boy kill the flowers when he steps on them or cut them? Semantically it makes sense. Maybe you just meant that "alguién mató mis flores" is not idiomatic in Spanish?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Exactly. We generally don't refer to plants as being "killed", at least not when the "killer" is human.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes, I mentioned "personal *a*" because you wrote that it's used when the DO is a person, which was only partially correct and had to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: "Alguien mató mis flores" sounds funny for both meanings of "funny".

Comment: I agree with @Gustavson and pablodf76: "El chico mató mis flores" and "Alguien mató mis flores" sound really odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=a, "a" is also required before a direct object when it comes :

> m) Ante nombres de cosa que designan colectivos formados por personas, del tipo colegio, empresa, comité, consejo, institución, comunidad, etc., cuando el verbo denota una acción que solo puede ejercerse sobre personas, y no sobre cosas: Multaron a la empresa por realizar vertidos tóxicos; Convocaron a la comunidad de vecinos para que tomara la decisión definitiva.

Translation to English:

> m) before things that designate collectives made up of people, such as a school, company, committee, council, institution, community, etc., when the verb denotes an action that can only be exercised on people, and not on things: The company was fined for carrying out toxic dumping; the community of neighbors was called upon to make the final decision.

"sumir" and "hundir" take "a" in your examples because "compañía" and "país" are collectives made up of people (for instance, "país" can be understood as "the people living in the country").

Answer (score 3):

The verb "sumir" always takes "a", perhaps because its objects are always personal or can be personified ("país" can be understood as "the people living in the country").

In the case of "hundir", it will take "a" when the object is personal or can be personified, and this will always be the case when the meaning is figurative (with "hundir" not meaning "submerge" or "cause the physical collapse" but "lead to banktruptcy" or "cause the financial collapse").

Comment: The verb sumir is always followed with "a"? How about the sentence "Sumió el pedal del auto hasta el fondo."

Comment: @sf_admin That sentence is not proper Spanish to my ears.

Comment: That's the sentence given at wordreference.com for the verb sumir: https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sumir

Comment: @sf_admin It may be some regional usage.

Comment: *Sumió el pedal* is not OK [according to the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/sumir?m=form). It's probably understandable and OK if someone uses it, but it sounds very, very odd.

Comment: @pablodf76 Could you please explain why "las decisiones del presidente acabaron sumiendo al país en un caos" (3rd example in my question) is OK according to that DLE link and "sumió el pedal del auto hasta el fondo" is not ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Here: https://www.google.com/search?q=sumir+diccionario&rlz=1C1GCEV_enAR827AR827&oq=sumir+diccionario&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.6336j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 you can find definitions and examples of "sumir". The only one that is hardly ever used (never heard or read it in my life) and which would be an exception to what I stated in my reply about "sumir" always taking "a" is "sumir los pies en el barro". None of the definitions renders "sumir el pedal" a possible sentence in Spanish.

Comment: @Gustavson I see "El tsunami sumió la ciudad bajo el agua" in https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/sumir

Comment: @AlanEvangelista That sounds better but continues to be odd to my ears. I've never seen or used "sumir" for physical actions. My advice to you is that you avoid using it in such concrete situations.

Comment: *Sumir en el caos* is metaphorical and it works because chaos is often assimilated to an abyss, like the depths of an ocean. Also by extension you can have *sumir en la anarquía / el desorden*. But such a concrete physical action like pushing down a pedal is never expressed with *sumir*. Actually no-one says *sumir* in everyday life; it's a formal or literary word.